# wordpress query to prevent null value

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a wordpress function that displays the birth date based on the users meta value.

```
<?php 
     $user_id = get_current_user_id(); 
     $key = 'Your Date'; 
     $single = true; 
     $user_last = get_user_meta( $user_id, $key, $single ); 
     echo $user_last; 
?>
```

I want to change the function such that if the birth date is not given  or null, the date should show today's date.

How can i achieve this

Answer (score 0):

I'd modify the line:

```
$user_last = get_user_meta( $user_id, $key, $single );
```

to:

```
$user_last = ($val = get_user_meta( $user_id, $key, $single ) ) ? $val : date("Ymd");
```

Just change the date format as needed (refer to http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).